# MySQLのJSON型に対応した、JavaかScalaで使えるORマッパーはありますか？

Tags: java, mysql, json, scala, postgresql

MySQLのJSON型に対応した、JavaかScalaで使えるORマッパーはありますか？
PostgreSQLのJSON型を扱えるORMでもOKです。

以下は非対応だったORMです。

- Slick -> NG
- Anorm -> NG
- mapperdao -> NG
- morpheus -> NG
- mysql-async -> NG

Comment: slick-pgというライブラリが対応している模様 https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1456#issuecomment-194383332